# Почему не работает данный код typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend

Я хочу перебрать изображения и получить их ключ. Но не могу понять, почему данный код не работает:

```
const tokenCheckboxes: ReactNode[] = images.map((image: ReactNode) => {
const name: string = image!["key" as keyof Object];
console.log(name);

return image;})
```

В то время как данный код работает:

```
const tokenCheckboxes: ReactNode[] = images.map((image: ReactNode) => {
const name: string = image!["key" as keyof Object] as unknown as string;
console.log(name);
return image;})
```

Ошибка при первом коде:

> TS2322: Type 'Function | (() => string) | (() => string) | (() => Object) | ((v: PropertyKey) => boolean) | ((v: Object) => boolean) | ((v: PropertyKey) => boolean) | ... 5 more ... | (() => boolean)' is not assignable to type 'string'.   Type 'Function' is not assignable to type 'string'.**

Answer (score 1):

Выражением `"key" as keyof Object` вы сказали, что `"key"` - это какое-то из свойств `Object`. Поскольку компилятор не знает, какое именно ( поскольку `keyof Object` - не литерал, а совокупность литералов ), то он будет проверять типы среди всех свойств `Object`: `constructor`, `hasOwnProperty`, `toString` и т.д. Среди них нет ни одной, которая имела бы тип строки, на что и ругается тайпскрипт. Короче, это выражение - полный бред. Второе работало только потому, что вы скастовали тип, однако это будет только компилироваться, а не стабильно работать.

##### Теперь попробуем написать рабочее решение:

Для начала отмечу, что `ReactNode` - это объединение разных типов, и не все из них содержат `"key"`.

Соответственно, для начала было бы неплохо проверить, что `image` содержит свойство `"key"` ( и сделать ещё проверку на то, что `image` - это объект, иначе компилятор взбеситься ):

```typescript
if(node && typeof node === "object" && "key" in node) {
    const key = node.key;
    // key: string | number | null
}
```

Теперь компилятор знает, что `image.key` существует, однако `image.key` может ещё оказаться и `null`, это тоже надо проверить.

В итоге получаеться такой вот код:

```typescript
const tokenCheckboxes: ReactNode[] = images.map((image: ReactNode) => {
    if(image && typeof image === "object" && "key" in image) {
        const key = image.key;

        if(key !== null) {
            console.log(key);
        }
    }
    
    return image;
})
```

Всё становиться проще, если `images` - это массив изначально `ReactElement`. В таком случае никаких проверок на существование ключа `"key"` делать не надо   ( и лучше попробуйте этот вариант сначала, если не уверены, какой именно тип у `images` ):

```typescript
const tokenCheckboxes = images.map((image) => {
    if(image.key !== null) {
        const key: number | string = image.key;

        console.log(key);
    }
    
    return image;
})
```